# enabled submit button after checked and terms downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a checkbox function which enables a form submission once one of the checkboxes have been ticked.  [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/bphze/76/) I would like to know if it's possible to add more to this function, once the checkbox has been check it automatically downloads a file, can this been done ?

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: _can this been done ?_ yes! but how is your downloadable url looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `download` property introduced in html5:

```js
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        $('<a>', {
            "id":"downloadFile",
            text:'download file!',
            href:'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/eye-24-256.png'})
            .prop('download', 'download') // add a download property
            .appendTo(document.body); // append to document.
        
          $('#downloadFile')[0].click();// apply a click to download.
          $('#downloadFile').remove(); // then remove it from dom
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox'/>
```

---

[As per your comment, this could help you.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/async-script-loader-with-callback/)

Comment: @NewBoy just added you can take a look at it.

Comment: thanks is there a way to make the link to open is a new window ?

Comment: why do you want to do this way?  as this code can be done in that way too.

Comment: @NewBoy i don't think opening a new window is good user experience, it irritates actually.

Comment: that's your opinion…. it's what i have been assigned to do

Comment: Okay! put this code in window.open() and just execute it.

Comment: hey only, is there a way to remove the download class once the terms has been clicked

Comment: `download` property which added to the element? you can set it to false or just remove it.

Comment: I don't get it if we are removing it after click and there is no download class added. Which one you are mentioning, i would post an edit if you clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. Just write below code

```
checkboxes.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'uploads/file.doc';
});
```

You can also check for the id of each checkbox in case you need to download different files based on checked boxes.

```
checkboxes.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    if (this.id == 'option-1')
        window.location.href = 'uploads/file.doc';
    if (this.id == 'option-2')
        window.location.href = 'uploads/file1.doc';
    and so on.....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on Change Listeners

```
$('#option-1').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // do downloading options
        confirm("Are you sure want to download?");
     }
});
```